# Change the value of a variable depending on a radio button

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, radio-button

I have a variable called genderMultiplier which is used in this calculation

```
const bloodAlcoholContent = (gramsOfAlcohol / ((weight * 1000) * genderMultiplyer))*100;
```

My genderMultiplier can have 2 values and I have made a radio input for that in HTML

```
<div class="gender-buttons" id="gender-buttons">
     <input class="gender-button" type="radio" name="tools" id="tool-1" value="0.55" checked>
     <label class="for-gender-button" for="tool-1">Male</label>
     <input class="gender-button" type="radio" name="tools" id="tool-2" value="0.68">
     <label class="for-gender-button" for="tool-2">Female</label>
</div>

const genderButtonElement = document.getElementById("gender-buttons")
const genderMultiplyer = parseFloat(genderButtonElement.input);
```

One radio button is [MALE] and [FEMALE]. So if the user clicks  Male then I want the genderMultiplier to be 0.55 and if the user clicks Female then I want the genderMultiplier to be 0.68

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

Change your last line to

```
const genderMultiplier = parseFloat([...genderButtonElement.children].find(c=>c.checked).value)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getMultiplier()
{

const genderMultiplyer = parseFloat(document.querySelector('input[name="tools"]:checked').value);

alert("The multiplier is: " + genderMultiplyer);
}
```

```html
<div class="gender-buttons" id="gender-buttons">
     <input class="gender-button" type="radio" name="tools" id="tool-1" value="0.55" checked>
     <label class="for-gender-button" for="tool-1">Male</label>
     <input class="gender-button" type="radio" name="tools" id="tool-2" value="0.68">
     <label class="for-gender-button" for="tool-2">Female</label>
</div>

<button onclick="getMultiplier()">Get Multiplier</button>
```

The pure Javascript way of doing this in your example is as follows:

`const genderMultiplyer = parseFloat(document.querySelector('input[name="tools"]:checked').value);`

If your are using JQuery you can get it this way:

`const genderMultiplyer = parseFloat($('input[name="tools"]:checked').val());`

Comment: @MoMiah Is it giving you an error? Which version did you try? If you tried the JQuery version, do you have JQuery loaded? Cheers

Comment: Im using the normal version. 
const genderButtonElement = document.querySelector('input[name="tools"]:checked');

But when I click the calculation, it only uses the male value (0.55) as the variable and when I click on the female button nothing changes. 

Thnks

Comment: I added a working example for you to see.

Comment: Thanks for that, is there any way I can use the answer of the function getMultiplier() in a calculation? That's what I've tried to do but doesn't seem to be working. I've clicked on the male button which gives me an answer but when I click the female button the answer doesn't change.

Comment: Yes, you can use the result of getMultiplier(). Instead of `alert(...)`, use `return genderMultiplyer;`. If you've copied and pasted the code above, you will get the correct multiplier. If all of this answers you're original question, please mark it as the answer. Cheers!

Comment: So I've used the answer like this - 

const bloodAlcoholContent = (gramsOfAlcohol / ((weight * 1000) * genderMultiplier))*100;

When I click the male button it calculates for male but when I click female it doesnt change the answer?

Answer (score 1):

To calculate `bloodAlcoholContent`, you need to know the values `gramsOfAlcohol` and `weight`. But you did not show the method for calculating these variables.

```js
const genderButtonElement = document.querySelectorAll('.gender-buttons .gender-button');
genderButtonElement.forEach(function(current, index) {
  current.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const genderMultiplyer = parseFloat(current.value);
    console.log(genderMultiplyer);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="gender-buttons" id="gender-buttons">
     <input class="gender-button" type="radio" name="tools" id="tool-1" value="0.55" checked>
     <label class="for-gender-button" for="tool-1">Male</label>
     <input class="gender-button" type="radio" name="tools" id="tool-2" value="0.68">
     <label class="for-gender-button" for="tool-2">Female</label>
</div>
```